# looping over a few file extensions in bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have a list of files in a folder and I want to just work on a few of them. The folder contains files with file.qc, file.qc.gz file.qc.stat file.qc.count and so on.

I want to write a loop in bash that will open only the file.qc and file.qc.gz, while ignoring other file extensions (such as qc.stats or qc.count)

Comment: I tried this but also I want to edit the files epartely, i.e. .qc and .qc.gz needs diffrent awk statemts for which its giving me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify multiple globs in your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Gracefully cases where there are no matches
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.qc *.qc.gz
do
  echo "Found: $f"
done
```

You can also write this shorter as `*.qc{,.gz}`, which expands to the same thing.

Comment: I tried this but also I want to edit the files epartely, i.e. .qc and .qc.gz needs diffrent awk statemts for which its giving me an error

Comment: This loops over all the files you want. It's up to you to do something useful with them. If you want to do an operation conditionally, you can use an `if` statement. For example `echo "This code runs for all files"; if [[ $f == *.qc.gz ]]; then echo "This code only runs for .qc.gz files"; fi`